# Problems with loading Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi all I've just started with Javascript and i wanted to use d3 and I already met into a problem:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://blahblah/api/votes. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This problem was shown in my console.

Attached is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Testbed!</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <script>

        d3.select("body").append("p").text("hi, whats up");
        console.log(d3);

        d3.json("https://blahblah/api/votes", function(data) {

            var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 500)
                        .attr("height", 500)

            canvas.selectAll("rect")
                        .data(data) //the data in the bracket is because our function uses the varible data
                        .enter()
                            .append("rect")
                            .attr("width", function(d) { return d; })
                            .attr("height", 50)
                            .attr("y", function(d,i) { return i*10; })
                            .attr("fill", "blue");

            canvas.selectAll("text")
                        .data(data)
                        .enter()
                            .append("text")
                            .attr("fill", "white")
                            .attr("y", function(d,i) { return i*50; })
                            .text(function (d) { return d.document_id + 25; })

        })
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Can someone give me some clues as to what is going on?

Comment: Read this: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: You can't do Ajax calls to resources on a different domain than you are running unless they give you access to do so or unless the service supports JSONP and you use that (which doesn't even actually make an Ajax call, it uses a `<script>` tag).  I'd suggest you read up on how the specific API you're trying to use supports cross-domain access.

Comment: See one of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bd3.js%5D+Access-Control-Allow-Origin